# I want my block to overlap another block whenever I hover over them in HTML

Tags: html, css, hover

I have made two div side by side and want to increase the size of my div whenever I hover the div. But the problem I am facing is that whenever I hover the div it move to the bottom.
This is my HTML and CSS code.

```css
.col-1,.col-2{
width: 49%;
height: 300px;
border: 2px solid red;
float:left;
}
.container:hover{
width: 50%;
height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
</div>
```

I want my block to overlap another block whenever I hover over my block.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is you can use css scaling effect with the combination of the transition effect

```css
.col-1,.col-2{
width: 49%;
height: 300px;
border: 2px solid red;
float:left;
transition:0.3s ease-in;
}

.col-1:hover, .col-2:hover{
transform:scale(1.1);
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
-moz-transform:scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
</div>
```